# XPath query selecting highest empty ancestor if all children and grand-children etc are recursively empty?

Tags: xml, recursion, xpath

An '**empty**' tag in my context is recursively defined as those tags whose text() is empty or if all its children are '**empty**'.
In a generic XML can we know all the top-level '**empty**' tags?Here is an example

```
<grand-parent>
  <parent1>
    <child1>v1</child1>
    <child2>v2</child2>
    <child3>v3</child3>
    <child4></child4>
  </parent1>
  <parent2>
    <child1>
     <gc></gc>
    </child1>
    <child2></child2>
  </parent2>
</grand-parent>
```

I need the nodes `child4` and `parent2` as the output.Can we do this using a XPath query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (assuming XPath 1.0):

```
grand-parent//*[normalize-space(.) = ''][normalize-space(..) != '']
```

This works by the following principles:

- `grand-parent//` means *from `grand-parent` node recursively, depth-first, in document order, all descendants or self*
- `*` is short for *any element*, in XPath 2.0 this is clearer written as `element()`. The default axis is the child-axis, so essentially it is short for `child::element()` (or `child::*` in XPath 1.0), meaning it selects any element on the current element that is a child. Since we started with `//`, it selects any child of any parent.
- `[..]` contains a *predicate*, which contains an expression that is applied to the current node. If true (if numeric, it its the xth node starting from the first child on the current axis), select that node.
- `.` means the current node
- `normalize-space(.) = ''` means: remove any double spaces, or any trailing or leading spaces. Atomization occurs on `.`, which essentially means: concatenate all text values of all children of the current node. In other words: if any child at any depth exists of only spaces, this is true.
- `..` means: select the parent node. This is short for `parent::node()`, but effectively this always selects an element or root (document) node, as only elements and document node can have children.
- `normalize-space(..) != ''` means: atomize the parent (and by definition, also all its children and deeper descendants) of the current node. If at any depth this only contains spaces, *this predicate will return false*.

A relatively simple expression but a long explanation ;). An invariant of your requirement is that if an element is empty (by your definition) and its parent is not empty, then this must be the highest element that (recursively) is empty. Otherwise, the parent element will also be empty and the last predicate will return false.

Comment: @Abel thanks, can you explain how does this recursively compute the top-node?Or point me to some sources?I could only understand this as 'all nodes for which all children are non-empty and grand-children are empty'

Comment: @themanwhosoldtheworld, done! Please see my extended explanation. Hope it helps, but feel free to ask if anything is not clear.